# Why am I getting color quantization artifacts using PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm using the package `gif` [here](https://github.com/maxhumber/gif) to string together matplotlib plots in to gifs. However, I'm getting artifacts in the images due to the colors being... I don't know the formal word but "down-sampled."

The original plots look like this: [image: example_image]

smooth consistent color changes in the colormaps.

However, when I use the package to covert to gif I get this:

[image: gif_output]

Hopefully you can see the quantization/down-sampling that happens in the colors.

The code that actually runs is very short (with a line that I added to try to make the color correction work properly, but it didn't work -- the gif uploaded is with this correction, but it looks identical to what it was doing before)

````
def frame(func):
    """
    Decorator for a matplotlib plot function.

    Example:
    ```
    @gif.frame
    def plot(x, y):
        plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        plt.xlim((0, 100))
        plt.ylim((0, 100))
    ```
    """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        plt.savefig(buffer, format="png")
        buffer.seek(0)
        image = Image.open(buffer)
        ### ADDED IN AFTER THE FACT ###
        image = image.convert('RGBA', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
        ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
        plt.close()
        return image

    return wrapper


def save(frames, path, duration=100):
    """
    Save decorated frames to an animated gif.

    - frames (list): collection of frames built with the frame decorator
    - path (str): filename with relative or absolute path
    - duration (int): milliseconds between frames
    """
    frames[0].save(
        path,
        save_all=True,
        append_images=frames[1:],
        optimize=True,
        duration=duration,
        loop=0,
    )
````

Any idea what I can do with the package PIL that will maintain the continuity of the colormaps when writing out to gifs? Would the dpi/file-size just have to be very large to maintain that?

Here's the code that produced the plot, just in case:

```
@gif.frame
def plot_signal_and_ft(t, t_step):
    ### Setup ###
    dims = (501,501)
    x = np.linspace(0,100,dims[0])
    y = np.linspace(0,100,dims[1])
    u = float(100/dims[0])
    cen = [50.0, 50.0]
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
    signal = np.zeros(dims)
    r = 25*(0.003125*np.exp(5.66643*(t/t_step))+0.046875)
    offset = 1.0 + ((25.0-1.0)/(t_step))*t
    pos1 = np.sqrt((xx-cen[0]+offset)*(xx-cen[0]+offset)+(yy-cen[1])*(yy-cen[1]))
    pos2 = np.sqrt((xx-cen[0]-offset)*(xx-cen[0]-offset)+(yy-cen[1])*(yy-cen[1]))
    sigma, mu = r, 0
    signal += np.exp(-( (pos1-mu)**2 / ( 2.0 * sigma**2 ) ) )
    signal += np.exp(-( (pos2-mu)**2 / ( 2.0 * sigma**2 ) ) )

    # FT
    F = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(signal))
    max_real = 10.0
    max_imag = 3.0

    ### PLOTTING ###
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), nrows=2, ncols=2, dpi=100)
    # SIGNAL 
    sig = ax[0,0].imshow(signal, cmap = plt.cm.Greys, vmin=0, vmax=1, origin="lower")
    ax[0,0].axis("off")
    ax[0,0].set_title("Signal", fontsize="medium", fontweight="bold",fontfamily="serif")
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax[0,0])
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
    cbar = f.colorbar(sig, cax=cax)
    cbar.set_ticklabels(["0.0", "0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "1.0"])
    # REAL
    real = ax[1,0].imshow(np.real(F), cmap=mpl.cm.RdBu, clim=(-max_real, max_real), 
                        norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.0, vmin=-max_real, vmax=max_real), 
                        origin="lower")
    ax[1,0].axis("off")
    ax[1,0].set_title("R[FT]", fontsize="medium", fontweight="bold",fontfamily="serif")
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax[1,0])
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
    f.colorbar(real, cax=cax)
    # IMAG
    imag = ax[1,1].imshow(np.imag(F), cmap=mpl.cm.PiYG, clim=(-max_imag, max_imag), 
                        norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.0, vmin=-max_imag, vmax=max_imag), 
                        origin="lower")
    ax[1,1].axis("off")
    ax[1,1].set_title("Im[FT]", fontsize="medium", fontweight="bold",fontfamily="serif")
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax[1,1])
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
    f.colorbar(imag, cax=cax)
    # MAGNITUDE
    mag = ax[0,1].imshow(np.absolute(F), cmap=plt.cm.hot, clim=(0, max_real), 
                     norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=max_real/2, vmin=0, vmax=max_real), 
                     origin="lower")
    ax[0,1].axis("off")
    ax[0,1].set_title("||FT||", fontsize="medium", fontweight="bold",fontfamily="serif")
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax[0,1])
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
    f.colorbar(mag, cax=cax)

    plt.tight_layout()

t_steps = 10
frames = []
traj = [t for t in range(t_steps)] + [t_steps-t for t in range(t_steps)]
for t in traj:
    frame = plot_signal_and_ft(t, t_steps)
    frames.append(frame)

gif.save(frames, "./test_double.gif", duration=150)
```

Comment: Try `image = image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)` - you need the images in palette format anyway in order to be stored as GIF.

Comment: Hmmm... I still get color quantization using `image = image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't even understand half your code so I apologize if my answer is wrong in any way, but I have a fairly good understanding of digital images.

Unfortunately the gif format only support 256 color variations, which will never produce a decent gradient. You could explore some options such as image dithering (available in pil `image.convert` https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) but you are mostly stuck with this kind of quality when doing .gif. Some complex solutions exist to get more colors in a .gif but the size will increase a lot, and those solutions are above my head so I'll let you research them (read the NOTE: https://techterms.com/definition/gif).

I'd suggest trying to see if you could use another format for your project. But again, I'm not even sure what it is you are doing precisely.